Issue with Real Time Arm Servoing on Franka Emika Panda Robot using MoveIt!
Description:
I am a beginner in ROS 1 programming and I am encountering an issue that I hope to resolve with your assistance.
I am attempting to implement Real Time Arm Servoing (Link) on my Franka Emika Panda Robot Arm using MoveIt! 1 to control the end-effector velocity. However, the command message sent from the servo_server node results in erratic and rapid movement of the robot, followed by a halt and the display of the following joint warning:
[ WARN] [1713359697.229103201]: FrankaHW: 
panda_joint4: 2.794856 degrees to joint limits (limits: [-3.071800, -0.069800] q: -3.023021) 
panda_joint7: 3.113240 degrees to joint limits (limits: [-2.897300, 2.897300] q: -2.951636) 

Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
ROS Distro: Noetic
ROS 1
Robot: Franka Emika Panda

Setup:
I launch the Panda Robot using the command: roslaunch panda_moveit_config franka_control.launch robot_ip:=172.16.0.2 load_gripper:=false
Next, I launch the default servo_server node present in the MoveIt package with the configuration YAML file (see below for details):
###############################################
# Modify all parameters related to servoing here
###############################################
use_gazebo: false # Whether the robot is started in a Gazebo simulation environment

## Properties of incoming commands
command_in_type: "speed_units" # "unitless"> in the range [-1:1], as if from joystick. "speed_units"> cmds are in m/s and rad/s
scale:
  # Scale parameters are only used if command_in_type=="unitless"
  linear:  0.01 # Max linear velocity. Meters per publish_period. Unit is [m/s]. Only used for Cartesian commands.
  rotational:  0.03 # Max angular velocity. Rads per publish_period. Unit is [rad/s]. Only used for Cartesian commands.
  # Max joint angular/linear velocity. Rads or Meters per publish period. Only used for joint commands on joint_command_in_topic.
  joint: 0.01
low_pass_filter_coeff: 10 #2.  # Larger --> trust the filtered data more, trust the measurements less.

## Properties of outgoing commands
# publish_period: 0.008  # 1/Nominal publish rate [seconds]
publish_period: 0.008  # 1/Nominal publish rate [seconds]
low_latency_mode: false  # Set this to true to publish as soon as an incoming Twist command is received (publish_period is ignored)

# What type of topic does your robot driver expect?
# Currently supported are std_msgs/Float64MultiArray (for ros_control JointGroupVelocityController or JointGroupPositionController)
# or trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory (for Universal Robots and other non-ros_control robots)
# command_out_type: std_msgs/Float64MultiArray
command_out_type: std_msgs/Float64MultiArray

# What to publish? Can save some bandwidth as most robots only require positions or velocities
publish_joint_positions: true
publish_joint_velocities: false
publish_joint_accelerations: false

## MoveIt properties
move_group_name:  panda_arm  # Often 'manipulator' or 'arm'
planning_frame: panda_link0  # The MoveIt planning frame. Often 'base_link' or 'world'

## Other frames
ee_frame_name: panda_link8  # The name of the end effector link, used to return the EE pose
robot_link_command_frame:  panda_link0  # commands must be given in the frame of a robot link. Usually either the base or end effector

## Stopping behaviour
incoming_command_timeout:  1000  # Stop servoing if X seconds elapse without a new command
# If 0, republish commands forever even if the robot is stationary. Otherwise, specify num. to publish.
# Important because ROS may drop some messages and we need the robot to halt reliably.
num_outgoing_halt_msgs_to_publish: 4

## Configure handling of singularities and joint limits
lower_singularity_threshold:  17  # Start decelerating when the condition number hits this (close to singularity)
hard_stop_singularity_threshold: 30 # Stop when the condition number hits this
joint_limit_margin: 0.2 # added as a buffer to joint limits [radians]. If moving quickly, make this larger.

## Topic names
cartesian_command_in_topic: delta_twist_cmds  # Topic for incoming Cartesian twist commands
joint_command_in_topic: delta_joint_cmds # Topic for incoming joint angle commands
joint_topic: joint_states
status_topic: status # Publish status to this topic
command_out_topic: /joint_group_velocity_controller/command # Publish outgoing commands here

## Collision checking for the entire robot body
check_collisions: true # Check collisions?
collision_check_rate: 50 # [Hz] Collision-checking can easily bog down a CPU if done too often.
# Two collision check algorithms are available:
# "threshold_distance" begins slowing down when nearer than a specified distance. Good if you want to tune collision thresholds manually.
# "stop_distance" stops if a collision is nearer than the worst-case stopping distance and the distance is decreasing. Requires joint acceleration limits
collision_check_type: threshold_distance
# Parameters for "threshold_distance"-type collision checking
self_collision_proximity_threshold: 0.01 # Start decelerating when a self-collision is this far [m]
scene_collision_proximity_threshold: 0.05 # Start decelerating when a scene collision is this far [m]
# Parameters for "stop_distance"-type collision checking
collision_distance_safety_factor: 1000 # Must be >= 1. A large safety factor is recommended to account for latency
min_allowable_collision_distance: 0.01 # Stop if a collision is closer than this [m]

Results:
The output from my custom ROS node, as shown by rostopic echo /servo_server/delta_twist_cmds, is as follows:
header: 
  seq: 13623
  stamp: 
    secs: 1713364260
    nsecs: 114695310
  frame_id: ''
twist: 
  linear: 
    x: 0.0
    y: -0.01
    z: 0.0
  angular: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0

Using these values, the servo_server node outputs the following on rostopic echo /joint_group_velocity_controller/command:
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [-0.3044424197392638, -0.22295786511951368, 0.3687497634653843, -2.330011008413096, 0.18752483420031713, 2.2479924510803877, -2.6017839107796616]
---
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [-0.30445233091205265, -0.22295958332877888, 0.36873282547494607, -2.3300136736512083, 0.18752542360820632, 2.247990331635926, -2.6018109931648112]
---
layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: [-0.3044604235913673, -0.2229609883831148, 0.36871929613099735, -2.330015854397797, 0.1875257764262996, 2.247988607898856, -2.601833475181157]
---

Node Graph:
I have attached a screenshot of the node graph for reference.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.
